# How to create an automatically managed "last update" field with Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

Originally I thought to ask if there would be an easy way to provide an automatically managed last update field with MS Access.

After some googling I found following approach:

```
Private Sub Form_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)

   Me.Last_Update = Date()

End Sub
```

Which seems to do the job. I thought I'd share it with others too (and if somebody has some good points that should be considered, feel free to share them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also put that same code into a BeforeUpdate.

The difference being that the OnDirty will tag the record when you first started to edit the record; while the BeforeUpdate will tag the record just before it gets committed to the database.

The latter may be preferable if you have a user who starts editing a record, goes to a meeting and then finishes editing it an hour later.

Comment: BeforeUpdate is certainly the correct event to use, not OnDirty.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, add a column Validation Rule (or `CHECK` constraint) to ensure the 'timestamp' column is updated when the table is being updated other than via your form. The SQL DLL (ANSI-92 Query Mode syntax) would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
   key_col INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
   data_col INTEGER NOT NULL
)
;
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD
   my_timestamp_col  DATETIME 
      DEFAULT NOW() 
   NOT NULL
;
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD
   CONSTRAINT my_timestamp_col__must_be_current_timestamp
      CHECK (my_timestamp_col = NOW())
;
```

Another approach when using Jet 4.0 (pre-Access 2007 i.e. before user level security was removed from the engine) is to create a 'helper' Jet SQL `PROCEDURE` (Access term: stored Query object defined using an SQL 'Action' statement, as distinct from a SQL `SELECT` query) that automatically updates the 'timestamp' column then remove 'update' privileges from the table and grant them instead on the `PROC` e.g. SQL DDL/DCL something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc 
(
   arg_key INTEGER, 
   arg_new_data INTEGER
)
AS 
UPDATE MyTable
   SET data_col = arg_new_data, 
       my_timestamp_col = NOW()
 WHERE key_col = arg_key
;
REVOKE UPDATE ON MyTable FROM PUBLIC
;
GRANT UPDATE ON MyProc TO PUBLIC
;
```

The advantage here is all updates must go via the `PROC` and therefore is under the developer's control; the disadvantage is Access/Jet SQL is that your form will also have to use the `PROC`, which means a paradigm shift away from the standard 'data bound forms' approach for which Access is famous.

Comment: I am very confused by this answer. Are you answering for a Jet back end or for SQL Server? If Jet, then there are no triggers or stored procedures and you have to use form-level events to stamp the records (this works very well, in fact).

Comment: My answer is pure Access/Jet/ACE and all the code is ANSI-92 Query Mode Jet 4.0 syntax, try it ;-) Jet does indeed have PROCEDURE syntax. My point is that you don't actually *need* to use an Access form to achieve a timestamp in ACE/Jet.

Comment: [Here's a link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-procedure-statement-HP001032219.aspx) to the Access2003 Help for `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Answer (score 2):

That might be your best choice on an access database with an access back end- but if you've got a MS-SQL back end, put an update trigger on the table so that you can catch edits regardless of where they come from.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Table_stampUpdates] ON [dbo].[Table]
 FOR Update 
AS 
BEGIN 
UPDATE Table
SET 
modified_by = right(system_user, len(system_user) - charindex('\', system_user)), modified_on = getdate() 
FROM Table inner join inserted on Table.PrimaryKey = Inserted.PrimaryKey
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this in the days of ACE 16.0 (MS Access 2016/365) the answer above from onedaywhen, to use a CONSTRAINT clause, no longer seems to work, sadly. It would seem that ACE 16.0 fails on the constraint check with the NOW() keyword in it, when saving an edited record, and so doesn't update the date field to NOW(), but instead says the validation check failed - probably because the current value in the date field doesn't equal NOW(), and thus prevents you from doing any edit on any record, until you DROP the CONSTRAINT. (Blasted BASIC's dual use of the = operator for both becomes and equality check).

PS: You CAN add record level CHECK CONSTRAINTS via an ALTER TABLE command in ACE 16.0, but they must be added via ADO code in VBA, and cannot be added from the SQL editor in MS Access. i.e.

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT NameOfConstraint CHECK (ExpressionToCheck);"
```

The following web page is a good resource for learning about this.
[CodeKabinett: Table Level Validation Rules in MS Access](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=access-table-validation-rule)